# How to prove that shifting does not change the discrimintant?

Tags: polynomials, elliptic-curves, discriminant

I have an elliptic curve given of the form:

$$ E \hspace{2mm} : \hspace{2mm} y^2+a_1xy+a_3y=x^3+a_2x^2+a_4x+a_6.$$

The discriminant of $E$ is given by $$\Delta(E) = -b_2^2b_8-8b_4^3-27b_6^2+9b_2b_4b_6,$$where $ b_2=a_1^2+4a_4$, $ b_4=2a_4+a_1a_3 $, $b_6=a_3^2+4a_6$ and $b_8=a_1^2a_6+4a_2a_6-a_1a_3a_4+a_2a_3^2-a_4^2$. I now want to show that the discriminant is $\neq0$ if and only if the function $E$ is non-singular.

In order to show one direction I assume that there is a singular point in E, namely $(x_0,y_0)$ . 
Now a proof in a book says within one sentence: "Since the discriminant doesn't change by transformation $x=x+x_0$ and $y=y+y_0$ w.l.o.g. we can assume that the singular point is $(0,0)$."

But is there a simple way to see that the discriminant doesn't change within such a modification?

Thanks a lot for help

Comment: You can directly compute. It's "simple," as in "elementary." Though "complex," as in "tedious."

Comment: I know that I can directly compute it but I was just hoping there might be a more simple and elegant way to prove it - do you have an idea? :-)

Comment: The discriminant of a cubic in $x$ can be written as a product of the pairwise differences of the three roots. But these pairwise differences don't change if each root is shifted by the same amount. (Not sure how including $y$ changes things, so this is not a full answer.)

Comment: You could define an isometric change of variables.

Comment: There are other ways to define the discriminant , but if you want to relate them to the given equation you are going to need to do computation at some point. Something that makes elliptic curves very tractable is that much can be done explicitly, using equations. A general theory will only be able to say things about general curves. If you are satisfied with a general argument that there is a polynomial which checks if a cubic is singular, I can give you one, but it won't be as powerful as having these formula.

Comment: @Justin: How would that look like?

Comment: @ Semincalssical: Would it be wrong to treat y as a constant and do the transformation $x=x+x_0$ and later treat x as a constant and do the same for y?

Comment: @AreaMan: So you think if I want to prove what I want to prove there is no true way except calculating it explicitly?

Comment: @J.Doe I expect that is true, though I'm hardly an expert. You *can* however use a computer to verify this, which will make your life easier.

Comment: Okay thank you - I will just calculate it explicitly - not beautiful but correct... Thanks a lot: By the way, this already solves one direction; From knowing that $f(0,0)=0$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=0$  and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)=0$ we get that $a_6$, $a_4$ and $a_3$ equal 0 and by looking that the definition of the discriminant, it shows that the discriminant is 0 as well then

Comment: But now I want to show the backward direction; So if f is non-singular, the discriminant is also not zero; Does anyone have an idea how to manage that?

Comment: Wolfram says "The discriminant depends on the choice of equations, and can change after a change of variables"

Comment: What do you mean with change of variables?